# How to push up only edit text (with bottom content) when android keyboard is open?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-softkeyboard

This is my make up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chat_container"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/test_woman"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/headerContainer"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="@dimen/broadcast_live_stop_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/camera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:tint="@color/grey_camera"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_36dp" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/stopLive"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Stop live"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/camera"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_button_shape"
                    local:MvxBind="Click StopLive"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        <!---->
            <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/broadcast_live_stop_header"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/chat_message_margin_left_bottom_right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/chat_message_container_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/chat_message_margin_left_bottom_right"
                android:id="@+id/messageList"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_recycler_view"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputMessageContainer"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/broadcast_live_stop_header"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin_with_icon"
                android:background="@color/grey_background">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/likeBut"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:tint="@color/red_blur"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/emoji_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:tint="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/likeBut"
                    android:src="@drawable/smiley" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/send"
                    local:MvxBind="Click SendMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:tint="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white" />
            <!---->
                <hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconEditText
                    android:id="@+id/emojiInput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_shape"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/chat_message_margin_bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chat_message_margin_bottom"
                    local:MvxBind="Text Message, Mode=TwoWay"
                    android:hint="Write your comment..."
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_margin_with_icon"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emoji_btn"
                    local:emojiconSize="28sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qiNP.jpg) and [Second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V67uI.png)

> I'm tried everything:

`WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan,`
 `WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize` 
 `this.Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan).`
 **Nothing happen, always content is jumping. I want bottom content pushing up but other (including background image) stay in place. Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may misunderstood about `Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan`, by using `AdjustPan`, it will move the entire view without resizing page content to show the keyboard, for your scenario:

> I want bottom content pushing up but other (including background image) stay in place. Any suggestions?

What you need is just:

```
this.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

Comment: Same result. I've tried this, but all content jump over screen.

Comment: @TarasDidukh, remove your three rows of code and just add this code, I tested, works fine on emulator.

Comment: @TarasDidukh, I used a image and a `EditText` on the bottom to test this code, you can see the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQfW8.gif), is this what you need? Keep the whole image been seen and just `EditText` be pushed up?